# Robots.txt Disallow URLS that have specific words

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

I want to disallow URLs that have specific (seeds_) words in URLs
such as

```
www.example.com/tags/seeds_123-of-plant
www.example.com/tags/plant-have-seeds_124
www.example.com/tags/getting-seeds_78-out-of
```

In these URLs [ **Seeds_** ] is a specific character.

I tried all below of it.

```
disallow: /tags/*seeds_
disallow: /tags/*seeds
disallow: /tags/*seeds?
```

but nothing work because sometimes it showed in the middle of the URL.
please provide authentic answers, Because I tried a lot. And more importantly, **don't give an answer such as**

```
disallow: /tags/*seeds_123
disallow: /tags/*seeds_124?
```

Because I have almost 100+ URLs such as so I can't disallow all of them single by single

Comment: When you say you tried something and it didn’t work -- how did you try/test it?

Comment: I tried and test in google webmaster robot option. but now again I tried and it's work

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk means anything, so this would disallow anything containing seeds_ inside the tags directory.

disallow: /tags/*seeds_*

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why these not working that time. But Now they are working properly...

```
disallow: /tags/*seeds_
disallow: /tags/*seeds
```